# wget match regular expression

Tags: wget

First try with wget.

I'm trying to use it to match a regex and download all images starting with `https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?`from a given url.

However, this doesn't seem to work.

The url in question is the following:

https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=kary+perry+the+one+that+got+away+cover&scope=images

(I just need to download a limited number of picture from bing)

I'm trying with this command here:

```
wget -nd -r -P save -A '^https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?' https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=kary+perry+the+one+that+got+away+cover&scope=images
```

but it downloads the robot.txt files instead.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `robots.txt` file is there to stop you from performing bot operations on the site. `wget` will, by default abide by the wishes of the `robots.txt` file.

> Web site owners use the `/robots.txt` file to give instructions about their site to web robots; this is called The `Robots Exclusion Protocol`.
>
> It works likes this: a robot wants to vists a Web site URL, say http://www.example.com/welcome.html. Before it does so, it firsts checks for http://www.example.com/robots.txt, and finds:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

> The `User-agent: *` means this section applies to all robots. The `Disallow: /` tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.

---

In bing's `robots.txt` file we can see the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /account/
Disallow: /bfp/search
Disallow: /bing-site-safety
Disallow: /blogs/search/
Disallow: /entities/search
...
Allow: /shopping/$
Allow: /shopping$
...
Disallow: /th?
Disallow: /th$
...
```

So they don't want you mass downloading from that path, you could try `/shopping` though.

If you find a way to bypass the `robots.txt` file and perform the operation you want, you will be acting maliciously and the site will likely ban your IP.

---

[robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

---

**Conclusion**

You likely aren't doing anything wrong (*I'm not a wget expert by any means so there may be syntax errors as well*), but the action is just not permitted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very clear. No i'm not gonna try to bypass it as it is not the important, i would just like to be able to automatically download a picture but it seems to be way to restricted (i tried bing as Google is even worse :) ) If you have any suggestions they are welcome, otherwise I'll just give up and search/download them manually when in need. Thanks again